# The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am writing a simple application in EF 4.1 which will use add, delete , edit and detail form my common data source (central server for database).
In my Controller class i write:

```
    public class RegController : Controller
    {
       //
       // GET: /Reg/
       private string CmdStr =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConn"].ConnectionString;      
       public ActionResult Index()
      {
        using (var db = new RegModelContext(CmdStr))
        {
          return View(db.Registrant);
       }

    }
}
```

when I am executing my Application it gave me an error in index view at foreach statement:

```
@model IEnumerable<Registration.Models.Register>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                UserName
            </th>
            <th>
                Password
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Address
            </th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.UserName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Password
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Email
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Address
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is this:
    "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed."

Comment: You need to return db.Registrant.ToList(), because it tries to execute query after datacontext is disposed, ToList() will force to execute it sooner.

Answer (score 15):

You should use a List to pass as your model

i assume that db.Registrant return a list of users?, if so do something like this

```
List<Registrant> items = null;

using (var db = new RegModelContext(CmdStr))
{
    items = db.Registrant.ToList();
}

return View(items);
```

Comment: This time it gave an error on  items = db.Registrant.ToList(); That "
"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."

Comment: Why `from u ... select u` and not just `db.Registrant.ToList()`

Comment: @FahadMahmood what is the inner exception?

Answer (score 6):

Just to comment further, you need to separate your concerns.  You shouldn't use the database context like that in a controller.  Rather use it through a repository or service layer.

I also had this issue when using `using`.  I removed the using part.  Modify the code below to fit in with your scenario.  Assuming you are to bring back a list of users.  I would have this in my repository class:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
     MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext();

     public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
     {
          return dbContext.Users;
     }
}
```

This repository you then have injected in your controller by Autofac, Ninject, etc.

In your controller it would look something like this:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
     private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

     public UserController(IUserRepository userRepository)
     {
          this.userRepository = userRepository;
     }

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
          UserViewModel viewModel = new UserViewModel
          {
               Users = userRepository.GetAll()
          };
     }
}
```

And then in your view you can just loop through the users.

Comment: Probably because it was superfluous to the actual question. It probably shouldn't of really been down-voted, but at the same time it should not have been up-voted for the very same reason. Not every project one makes needs to adhere to SoC, especially if it's super simple