# "The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am new at Entity Framework Code first and I am building a small app to get used to it.When the site runs for the first time I access existing catalog values inside the database and display this in a drop down using razor.

```
public void GetCats()
    {
        using (context = new RecipeContext())
        {
            try
            {
                var query = (from r in context.Catalogues
                             select r).Distinct().ToList();

                catalogues = query.Select(t => t.CatalogueName.ToString()).ToList();
                catalogues.Sort();


            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                labMessage = exe.Message;

            }

        }
    }
```

Now when I try to add Catalogue values to the context I get the above error.

```
public void AddCatalogue(string catalogueName)
    {

        using(context = new RecipeContext())
        {
            try
            {
                catalogueName = catalogueName.ToLower();
                var catalogue = new RecipeCatalogue { CatalogueName = catalogueName };

                if (context.Catalogues.Where(t => t.CatalogueName == catalogueName).Count() > 0)
                {
                    labMessage = "The value already exists";
                    CatalogueNameAdded = false;
                    return;

                }
                context.Catalogues.Add(catalogue);
                context.SaveChanges();
                catalogueNameAdded = true;
                labMessage = "a new catalogue record was added";


            }
            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                catalogueNameAdded = false;
                labMessage = exe.Message;
            }

        }
    }
```

The values are being added to the database however but still get the above exception.

Advice perhaps as to why I get this error. This is my Controller method which calls the above method.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddNewCatalogue(string catalogueName)
    {
        ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
        model.AddCatalogue(catalogueName);
        return Json(new { ViewModel = model });

    }
```

Comment: I guess you should check which code cause `context` to be disposed

Comment: Is context a field in your model? If so do you do anything with it outside fo the methods you have copied here? Because if you do, you are working with a disposed context (it is disposed at the closing brace of the using statement)

Comment: possible duplicate of [The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859421/the-operation-cannot-be-completed-because-the-dbcontext-has-been-disposed)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is `context` a field in your model?
I think you shouldn't assign to a field in a using statement. At the closing brace of the using context will be disposed. If you access that field in another place (without re-assigning) you are accessing a disposed object that might raise the exception you are getting.

Try changing your using statetments like this `using (var context = new RecipeContext())`.
(note `var` before context) and drop the field.

Comment: @Arianule: But it does not explain an error in the posted code.

Comment: My guess would be that the exception is raised by another method that is using context after any of the posted methods has disposed it.

Answer (score 4):

Your context is being disposed when the `using` block where you're performing your query is exited. That's the whole point of the `using` statement:

```
using(context = new RecipeContext()) {
    // ...
}
// context has been disposed at this point
```

Instead of a `using` statement, give your class a field to hold a reference to it.

```
private RecipeContext _context;

public void GetCats() {
    _context = new RecipeContext();
    // ...
}

public void AddCatalogue(string catalogueName) {
    // Use _context here
}
```

Just make sure that at some point, you call `_context.Dispose()`. Also, it's probably better to create the context in the constructor or someplace else that's only called once, prior to performing any operations with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents:

The above answers are correct! If you're using some pattern like a repository, I sugest to implement it as a singleton! This way your objects will not be detached, and you're context will not be disposed!

Comment: Repository should return a List<T>. Then eager loading is implemented and DbContext can be disposed. Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18261732/the-operation-cannot-be-completed-because-the-dbcontext-has-been-disposed-exce