# The operation cannot be completed as DbContext has been disposed. Want to return selected table values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

My Controller Code is:-

```
public JsonResult FetchTblData()
    {
        string MyTableName = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["TblName"]);

        using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
        {
            try
            {
                Type tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
                switch (MyTableName)
                {
                    case "CourseTbl":
                        tableType = typeof(CourseTbl);
                        break;
                    case "CourseDescTbl":
                        tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
                        break;
                }

                var result = db.Set(tableType);

                return new JsonResult { Data = result, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
                return new JsonResult { Data = "Not Found", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }

        }
    }
```

I've looked in this question as well :- [The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed][1]

[1]: [The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11859421/the-operation-cannot-be-completed-because-the-dbcontext-has-been-disposed) and others but the approach is quite different . I want to have my table values in my jsonresult. But I can't access it via variable 'result'. Pardon my english.

Comment: Your returned `result` variable inherits from IEnumerable and doesn't seem to hold a value, but rather a prepared operation, which no longer can be executed over the `DbContext` it points to, because the `DbContext` gets disposed once the `return` is called, which happens just before .NET attempts to serialise `result` into JSON. Change your line `var result = db.Set(tableType);` to `var result = db.Set(tableType).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Giving me error :- The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

Comment: Try `result = db.Set<tableType>();`

Comment: Error:- tableType is a variable but used like a type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Set(tableType);
```

Is not a collection.  It's a query.  If you want to execute the query, then run

```
        var results = new List<object>();
        foreach (var item in db.Set(tableType))
        {
            results.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: It returns:-  dbset does not contain a definition for 'tolist' and no extention method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found.

Comment: Have you imported the System.Linq namespace?  It's an extension method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Right.  DbSet (the non-generic one) doesn't have any extension methods because it implements IEnumerable, not IEnumerable<T>.  Edited answer.

Comment: You saved me!! Are you an angle or something? :D

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
    public JsonResult FetchTblData()
    {

        string MyTableName = Convert.ToString(Request.Form["TblName"]);

        DbContext result;

        try
        {
            Type tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
            switch (MyTableName)
            {
                case "CourseTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseTbl);
                    break;
                case "CourseDescTbl":
                    tableType = typeof(CourseDesc);
                    break;
            }


            using (EBContext db = new EBContext())
            {
                result = db.Set(tableType);
            }

            return new JsonResult { Data = result, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) ? ex.InnerException.Message : "";
             return new JsonResult { Data = "Not Found", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's this:- I_DO_KNOW_TYPE_FOR_SET result ??

Comment: I meant that: I do not know the type

Comment: Maybe: DbContext result;

Comment: The problem here is I want to store my result in some variable which can be accessed in the angular json array.

Comment: and initialize it to?